# Inheritance and object copies

Tags: python

I'd like a `Derived` object to also "inherit" data from a `Base` object - how would that be done?

```
#!python3
#coding=utf-8

class Base:
    def __init__(self, attrib):
        self.attrib = attrib

listOfBaseObjects = [
    Base("this"),
    Base("that"),
    ]

print(listOfBaseObjects)

import copy

class Derived(Base):                        # ?
    def __init__(   self, baseObject,       # ?
                    otherattrib):
        #Base.__init__(baseObject)           # ?
        #self = copy.copy(baseObject)        # ?
        self.otherattrib = otherattrib

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Derived: {} {}>".format(self.attrib, self.otherattrib)

listOfDerivedObjects = [
    Derived(listOfBaseObjects[0], "this"),
    Derived(listOfBaseObjects[1], "that"),
    ]


print(listOfDerivedObjects)
# AttributeError: 'Derived' object has no attribute 'attrib'
```

Comment: You should decide whether you want to use [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) or [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).  Right now you're trying to do both, which doesn't really make sense.  See also [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) which uses composition to accomplish some things normally done with inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems not a problem about "inherit", you just want to merge the data from another object.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, attrib):
        self.attrib = attrib

listOfBaseObjects = [
    Base("this"),
    Base("that")
    ]

print(listOfBaseObjects)

class Derived():                        
    def __init__(self, baseObject, otherattrib):
        for key, value in vars(baseObject).items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
        self.otherattrib = otherattrib

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Derived: {} {}>".format(self.attrib, self.otherattrib)

listOfDerivedObjects = [
    Derived(listOfBaseObjects[0], "this"),
    Derived(listOfBaseObjects[1], "that"),
    ]


print(listOfDerivedObjects)
```

Comment: This "deep-copies" the data (attributes), and thus falls into the _composition_ category, correct?

Comment: @handle Seems you are right. I think if your base class has only attributes but no functions, it is far away from a class but similar with a container.